# How do I launch gnome-terminal directly from the Windows desktop?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have WSL2 set up with vcxsrv to launch GUI apps and this works great. However, the default terminal that shows up with the Ubuntu app on Windows is terrible. I can launch gnome-terminal from it, sure, but I'd like to be able to directly launch gnome-terminal from Windows.

I tried setting this as a shortcut: "C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe -c "cd && DISPLAY=:0 gnome-terminal"

However, running bash like this somehow doesn't allow it to find the X Server. "wsl --exec gnome-terminal" also gives the same result: cannot find X server.

How can I make this work?

and in case it's relevant, this is how I was able to get GUI apps running in the first place: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/running-wsl-gui-apps-on-windows-10/ba-p/1493242)

Also, I am not using the Insider Preview version of Windows 10 where this feature is built-in, which is why I have to use 3rd party software to do it.

Comment: In order to answer this question, you have to indicate if you are running the appropriate Insider Preview build of Windows 10.  Please [edit] your question to include this vital and required information.

Comment: Try `wsl ~ -e sh -c "DISPLAY=:0 gnome-terminal"`.  I have that working for a similar use-case.